# How can we send a follow up email for Wishlist?

Tags: email, magento, report

How can we send a email to the user reminding them that some products are available in their wishlist?
I have seen this functionality on many sites and I wish someone would have Implemented it by now.
There should be a way to Do this program way.
Also There is no way available in magento to see wishlist report,like which item is most available in wishlist or top 5 wishlist products.Is there a way to Implement Both the things

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no out of the box solution for both of your issues.

There does exist a $14.99 module that will give you more insight on wishlisted items and the relative customers: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-global-customer-wishlist-viewer.html

As for sending emails to those customers, this type of functionality exists in Magento Enterprise Edition.  You have the ability to automatically send emails to customers with wishlisted items - unless you are willing to shell out $15,000 for the enterprise version, you are a bit out of luck here.

You can either utilize a email blast service like MailChimp which integrates directly into magento to send focused email blasts OR do some custom development work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [MageMail](http://magemail.co).  (Full disclosure: I'm the founder of MageMail).

In case you're looking to build this custom, you basically just want to pull in the `wishlist_item` table and join on the customer table to get the customer associated with the wishlist item.

One gotcha to keep in mind is that all of the wishlist items are included in the same wishlist, regardless of when they were added (they're not like quotes in that regard).  So if you're building this custom, you'll want to make sure to build it in such a way that it will follow-up based on the date the wishlist item was added and not the date of the wishlist record itself.

I think that Enterprise has support for multiple wishlists but I haven't seen it in use much in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do exactly what you need the following way:
1. Segment your customers according to their wishlist records with [Market Segmentation Suite](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/market-segmentation-suite.html) extension. You can put users with particular wishlist item into a group or form a customer group of all users with non-empty wishlists. You can then export those segmented lists for future use.
2. Follow up your customers according to segmented lists you made with emails tailored to specific customer groups with [Follow Up Email](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/follow-up-email.html).

As for wishlist reports you can track which products have been added to customers’ wishlists, when the product has been added, how many days this item is in the wishlist with Advanced reports unit named Users Wishlists by aheadWorks.

So, these are 3 different extensions, but they definitely cope with the task you describe.